# OpenSSL binary for Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, openssl, solaris-10

Can someone tell me where I can find a pre-compiled binary of OpenSSL for Solaris 10?  I was told that there is a site called *"something like"* **`solarisfreeware.com`** but this doesn't exist.  I would also like to not have to register to download, such as with **`sunfreeware.com`**, which also turns out charges for the download from **`unixpackages.com`**.  There is a reason why I don't want to have to compile the source myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you remove the links to the websites, as they don't seem legit. Why don't you just simply compile the source on Solaris? Besides it seems Solaris 10 already comes with OpenSSL. If you want to install OpenSSL just run the following command http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/packages/solaris/sparc/html/00README.packages.html#Download and `pkgadd -d openssl.1.0.1e.SPARC.64bit.Solaris.10.pkg openssl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris 10 includes OpenSSL 0.9.7 out of the box, but it's in `/usr/sfw/lib` not the normal library path.

The [OpenCSW community package repository](http://www.opencsw.org/) seems to have precompiled packages of both [OpenSSL 0.9.8](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/libssl0_9_8/) and [OpenSSL 1.0.1](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/libssl1_0_0/) for Solaris 10, if you need functionality from a later version.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the OP It is available from [UNIX Packages](http://unixpackages.com)

Yes you have to pay for our service to compile then, but you do have the advantage that the packages are compiled by folks that have been doing this for over 20 years for the Solaris community, and they come with some level of support and provide all the required dependencies too

Note that the latest version 1.0.1.g that provides the Heatbleed fix was posted up for Solaris 8 - 11 on April 8.

Regards

Colin

Comment: The OP mentions that site already in his question